# GA Measurement Protocol: Too many goals end up as "direct" though sent with SubID

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We run a SEA review site and try to track leads that happen on our partners websites.
Every visitor gets a random UserID, which we send to GA together with the standard pixel and which we also use as Affiliate SubID. Our partners report our leads with corresponding SubIDs=UserIDs the next day.
Our tool pings those leads as "PageView=... from SubID=..." to GA via Measurement Protocol.

Good: 100% leads appear as "PageView" (and "Goal") in GA.
Bad: Only 75% are assigned correctly to "TrafficSource=Paid Search". 25% end up as "Direct"

What can I do?

I could parallely to SubID save the Gclid and send "PageView=... from SubID=... and GCLID=..." via Measurement Protocol??
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show an example of a measurement protocol string? Thx

Comment: After some days quality became better, only 28 out of 346 (8%) declared "direct" - mobile much better than desktop (still 15%).
I use batch to ping up to 20 pageviews at once:

https://www.google-analytics.com/batch

v=1 & tid=UA-193xxx-1 & uid=12345678901234567890 & t=pageview & dp=/leads/desktop/match-com
v=1 & tid=UA-193xxx-1 & uid=12345678901234567891 & t=pageview & dp=/leads/mobile/match-com
...
Thx for your help,